# self hosted mailing list

Tags: php, forum, mailing-list, ldap

I am looking for a mailing list or a forum software, that can be self-hosted. I was looking through different forum softwares like phpBB, IP-Board, vBulletin but none of them seems to have the feature of adding posts by mail (if that is wrong please correct me) which is mandatory.

A nice goody would be a LDAP-Authentication and the prefferd language would be php.

Any advice? Thanks a lot